# Can't access files on Magento root

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I am looking to install an SSL on my domain name and in order to do so I need to upload a .htm file to the root and access it via the browser, but when I do so, I keep getting a 404 error - this is with any .html page on the root - nothin shows up.

I have edited my htaccess file as well as deleting it all together and still no luck.

The file i'm trying to reach is: http://www.elmershardware.co.uk/xtt5ughh.htm

If someone could help point me in the right direction of fixing this I'd be really appreciative

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing to do with .htaccess. It's something related with your apache conf.
In your apache configuration file check if in `DirectoryIndex` appears

index.htm as a  entry, add it if it doesn't appears and restart apache. Then , try again

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. Where is it I find this file? As the servers are managed by a hosting company would this be something they would have to do?

Comment: Then , the best bet is to notice to your hosting provider about this issue. It must have a easy fix